# Transparently implementing a particular form of dynamic typing

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types

The basic idea is that I have a range of functions that work on any types from a particular class, but at runtime the program is supposed to read a configuration file and extract an element of one of the types in the class.

For instance, I have a 'Coefficient' class, various instances of it, and functions of various types that are polymorphic over types of that class; at runtime one particular type of that class is to be determined, and passed around.

---

I'm unsure how to properly address this; I tried making up 'compound' types, doing something like:

```
data CompoundCoeff = CompoundInt Int | CompoundDouble Double | ...
```

where Int, Double, ... are  instances of the class 'Coefficient'.
However, it started to become a big effort to adapt all the functions involved in the code to work with these compound types (and it's not a nice solution either, really). It would be OK if all functions had the same, easy type, e.g.

```
Coefficient a => a -> (stuff not involving a anymore)
```

but that's unfortunately not the case.

Another issue I ran into, is that I'm using type families, and have something like

```
class (Monoid (ColourData c), Coordinate (InputData c)) => ColourScheme c where
    type ColourData c :: *
    type InputData c  :: *
    colouriseData     :: c -> (ColourData c) -> AlphaColour Double
    processInput      :: c -> InputData c -> ColourData c
```

This doesn't go through cleanly if I have to use some sort of compound ColourData datatype, like the previous one; in particular I can no longer guarantee that the data stream gives a consistent type (and not just different 'subtypes' of a compound type), and would (among other things) have to make up a bogus Monoid instance if I did make up a compound ColourData type.

I've also looked into Data.Dynamic, but again I can't see how it would properly address the issues; the exact same problems seem to appear (well, slightly worse even, given that there is only one 'generic' Dynamic type as I understand it).

---

**Question:** How can I implement dynamic datatypes subordinate to particular classes, without having to rewrite all the functions involving those data types? It would be best if I didn't have to sacrifice any type safety, but I'm not too optimistic.
The program is supposed to read a configuration file at runtime, and all the requisite functions, polymorphic over the relevant class, are to be applied.

Answer (score 7):

The traditional way to provide an object that guarantees that it is an instance of typeclass `Foo`, but makes no additional guarantees, is like so:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialTypes #-}
 data SomeFoo = forall a . Foo a => SomeFoo a

 instance Foo SomeFoo where
   -- all operations just unwrap the SomeFoo straightforwardly
```

or, with GADTs, which might be more readable...

```
 data SomeFoo where
   SomeFoo :: Foo a => a -> SomeFoo
```

Answer (score 6):

One proposal would be to write a single top-level function that does all the finishing touches once you've chosen a type:

```
topLevel :: SomeTypeClass a => a -> IO ()
```

Your program can then be written something like this:

```
main = do
    config <- readConfig
    case config of
        UseDouble n -> topLevel n
        UseSymbolic x -> topLevel x
        UseWidgetFrobnosticator wf -> topLevel wf
```